# Why is the K8s UI not available when rancher is used?

Tags: rancher, kubernetes

K8s has been created using rancher, but when one would like to access the UI it shows:

```
Service unavailable
```

**Methods**

*Method 1*

- rancher was deployed locally using vagrant
- k8s was deployed
- click the ui button

*Method 2*

perhaps the local firewall was causing the issue?

- rancher was deployed on digital ocean
- k8s was deployed
- service unavailable again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've seen this happen, especially on the newest (as of now) version. Try going into the "Infrastructure stack" and look for stopped containers. Often it helps to just refresh the entire deployment (hit the button "up to date" next to the "kubernetes" stack and hit save (If I remember correctly) in the bottom to force the "refresh").

You could also try manually just restarting the kubernetes-dashboard containers.

Lastly you could use the kubectl cli to delete the dashboard pods and force them to get recreated.

Let me know how it goes! I know I had to do this fix a few times.

Comment: Restarting the containers on DO worked, but the issue persists if Vagrant is used. The logs do not indicate why.